# How do I return an object Array of Arraylists

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object, arraylist

This is the instance method from the UML diagram:

`public BankAccount[] getAllAccounts()`

The purpose of this method is to return all of the summary details of the customer's Bank Account.

BankAccount is class that contains the name, number of the account, balance and status:

```
    protected String name;
    protected String number;
    protected double balance;
    protected Status accountStatus;
```

Within the BankManager class, there is a instance variable:

`private ArrayList<BankAccount> acct;`

which contains an ArrayList of all the customer details from the BankAccount class.

In addition, there is also a `statement()` method in the BankAccount class which will return all the customer details in a String

So my question is, how can I return a Array of ArrayLists (using the `public BankAccount[] getAllAccounts()` method) which will print out all the customer details?

Comment: Are you trying to convert the `ArrayList` object (`acct`) into an array? or are you trying to return an array of `ArrayList` objects that are from a series of `BankManger` objects?

Comment: Yes I'm to convert an array of ```Arraylist``` objects that are a series of ```BankManager``` objects

Answer (score 0):

```
public BankAccount[] getAllAccounts() {
    if (acct != null) {
        acct.forEach(account -> {
            System.out.println(account.statement());
        });
        return acct.toArray(BankAccount[]::new);
    }
    return new BankAccount[0];
}
```

If `acct` is not null or empty, print all accounts details through `statement()` method, then convert  `acct` to an array and return it.

Hope this is what you want.